# Visual studio IDE Books

Tags: visual-studio

I wants to know in detail about how to debug efficiently in visual studio IDE. For this I wants to know the name of any good book on Visual studio IDE in relevant to C++ not C#.

I do need suggestion on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a book, but a good link from ScottGu on this subject: [Debugging Tips with Visual Studio 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/18/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

John Robbin's book was pretty good for all-purpose debugging.

I don't know about this book being used for a simple UI tutorial, but he gives a lot of information about how to get a debugger anywhere you need it, and what sorts of things are useful to look at.

http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/5822.aspx